# Eclipse, Creating Android Projects, won't import javax.swing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I normally create android apps using either eclipse or NetBeans but when I try to create a messagebox on button press, Eclipse in this case won't import javax.swing

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.understanding;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import javax.swing;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



      private void button1_ButtonActionPerformed(View v) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Account Details");
      }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.swing` does not exist on Android and [is not part of the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: what's the android equivalent? (of a messagebox) -  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Comment: @user3314757: What's the Android equivalent of... what?

Comment: @user3314757: There is no direct analogue to a messagebox, though you can create one via an `AlertDialog`. Note that displaying modal dialogs is not considered especially good form for mobile apps, so you may want to consider some alternative UI.